# mysqli Insert from multiple table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into mysqli from two table like this

```
INSERT INTO oc_lts_plan(vendor_id, subscription_id, name, no_of_product, join_fee, subscription_fee, validity, date_added, date_expire)
SELECT lv.vendor_id
FROM oc_lts_vendor lv
UNION ALL
SELECT ls.subscription_id, lsd.name, ls.no_of_product, ls.join_fee, ls.subscription_fee, ls.validity, now(), (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 month)
FROM oc_lts_subscription ls
    LEFT JOIN oc_lts_subscription_description lsd ON ls.subscription_id=lsd.subscription_id
WHERE ls.default_plan='1'
```

the error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Answer (score 0):

your second select has no match for the vendor_id column, if the vendor_id column is autogenerate, in this case, you can remove it on the first select

```
INSERT INTO oc_lts_plan(subscription_id, name, no_of_product, join_fee, subscription_fee, validity, date_added, date_expire)
SELECT lv.vendor_id
FROM oc_lts_vendor lv
UNION ALL
SELECT ls.subscription_id, lsd.name, ls.no_of_product, ls.join_fee, ls.subscription_fee, ls.validity, now(), (DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 1 month)
FROM oc_lts_subscription ls
    LEFT JOIN oc_lts_subscription_description lsd ON ls.subscription_id=lsd.subscription_id
WHERE ls.default_plan='1'
```

If your primary key is both (vendor_id, subscription_id), you will have no choice but to do the same on your second select, and that will depend on the structure of your second table

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM oc_lts_subscription ls LEFT JOIN oc_lts_subscription_description lsd ON ...' at line 1